# Did not find the solrconfig.xml and managed-schema in solr cloud example

Tags: solr

I am using the Apache solr. I run the solr cloud example but there is no schema file and solrconfig.xml file inside the node directory.

Comment: where did you check for the same?

Answer (score 5):

When you're running in cloud mode, configuration is stored inside Zookeeper. You can use the `bin/solr zk downconfig` and `upconfig` [commands to upload and download the configuration details](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_8/using-zookeeper-to-manage-configuration-files.html) from your cluster.

[**Download a configuration set**](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_8/solr-control-script-reference.html#download-a-configuration-set)

```
bin/solr zk downconfig -z 111.222.333.444:2181 -n mynewconfig -d /path/to/configset
```

[**Upload a configuration set**](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_8/solr-control-script-reference.html#upload-a-configuration-set)

```
bin/solr zk upconfig -z 111.222.333.444:2181 -n mynewconfig -d /path/to/configset
```

**Parameter reference**

> `-n <name>`
> Name of the configset in ZooKeeper to download. The Admin UI Cloud -> Tree -> configs node lists all available configuration sets.

> `-d <configset dir>`
> The path to write the downloaded configuration set into. If just a name is supplied, $SOLR_HOME/server/solr/configsets will be the parent. An absolute path may be supplied as well. *In either case, pre-existing configurations at the destination will be overwritten!*

> `-z <zkHost>`
> The ZooKeeper connection string. Unnecessary if ZK_HOST is defined in solr.in.sh or solr.in.cmd.